# Is selenium click asynchronus?

Tags: angularjs, selenium

I run automated test for angularjs website.
I have clicked on button with ng-click and the line after "element.click" was called before the ng-click method in the javascript file. It was very weird and it makes me think maybe the "element.click" call is asynchronus. 
I searched for people who asked this issue and didn't found any.

Comment: Use protractor. It's designed specifically to make tests reliable by plugging into the asynchronous mechanisms of AngularJS (I guess your code is doing asynchonous stuff, and not selenium, but you didn't post any line of it).

Comment: As @JBNizet suggested it is always best to use Protractor for Angular based application.